# How to render view from web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller named Categories and this has the api methods. I have a view named Index.cshtml under Categories folder

**Here is the layout**

```
Controller 
      -> CategoriesController

Views

      ->Categories 

         -> Index.cshtml
```

How to render the index view from CategoriesController?

Comment: is your `CatetoriesController` an MVC `Controller` or an `ApiController`? Please include some more code.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but views shouldn't be returned from a Web API as these should be designed to be consumed by many types of clients and not just web-based clients. Instead, create a separate ASP.NET MVC application, alongside your Web API, have that call your API and render a view based on the result.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/using-razor-together-with-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 0):

If class CategoriesController is a Web API controller and you are planning to use the RESTful design guidelines, then  as a Type it has to be derived from ApiController.
From your Index.cshtml , by using jquery or other .js library that provides Ajax services , you will query the HTTP verbs implemented by your controller. Hope it helps.